# Show button after click on banner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide banner and show button (form):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
;!( function( w, d ) {
    'use strict';
    var ad = { user: "1468238146", width: 234, height: 60, id: 'anetwork-' + ~~( Math.random() * 999999  ) },
    h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ],
    s = location.protocol + '//static-cdn.anetwork.ir/aw/aw.js';
    if ( typeof w.anetworkParams != 'object' )
    w.anetworkParams = {};
    d.write( '<div id="' + ad.id + '" style="display: inline-block"></div>' );
    w.anetworkParams[ ad.id ] = ad;
    d.write( '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + s + '" async></scri' + 'pt>' );
    })( this, document );</script>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<form action="http://google.com">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
    </form>";
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: share fiddle link with full code

Comment: Hi... script1 banner and script2 form button... i want after click on baner , show form in #demo

Comment: you put script tag inside the script tag

Comment: you can hide any element simply using the hide() function.

Comment: The script is the number one advertising ... The second script does not work

Comment: when clicking a banner you want show button right??

Comment: Yes ,,, i want click a banner show form

Answer (score 0):

Banner Click:
I assume you have banner [it may be button or any other element] and form.

```
<button id="banner">Banner</button>
<form id="form1" method="POST">
  //Elements goes here...
</form>



$('#banner').click(function(){
   $('#form1').show();
});
```